# MVC4 calling Javascript function from View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

The code below works if you enter a city and state, then click outside of the text box but NOT  directly on the Search submit button.  Clicking outside of the text box triggers the onblur event which fires the javascript code to run a bing maps geocode on the city and state and populates the two hidden text boxes with the latitude and longitude.  THEN when you click the submit button the code passes the latitude and longitude into the CityDistanceSort action on the Job controller which sorts the cities in the database based on their distance from the  latitude and longitude passed in, then posts that sorted model to the view.  Everything works except that you need to be able to enter the City and State and then of course just click the Submit button directly.  But doing so doesn't give the JS code time to geocode and causes an error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'SearchLatitude' of non-nullable type 'System.Double...

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("CityDistanceSort", "Job"))
{     
    <input type="hidden" name="SearchLatitude" id="SearchLatitude"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="SearchLongitude" id="SearchLongitude"> 
    <input type="text" name="CityStateName" id="CityStateName" placeholder="CITY, BY DISTANCE" onblur="GeocodeSearchCityState()">   
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
}
```

---

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CityDistanceSort(double SearchLatitude, double SearchLongitude)
    {
        var model = db.Jobs.ToList();
        foreach (var item in model)
            { item.PickupDistanceSort = ICN.CustomMethods.GetDistance(SearchLatitude, SearchLongitude, item.PickupLatitude, item.PickupLongitude); }
        return View("JobHeadings", model.OrderBy(s => s.PickupDistanceSort));
    }
```

Comment: Call your calculation function before submitting the form.

Comment: How do you call the function before the form is submitted without the user having to click two buttons?  One to call the calculation, and one to submit the form.  Plus, the calculation is being called before the form is submitted with the onblur event, but that is not working.

Comment: one way to achieve this is, make your submit button a normal button then on click of button call the calculate code and then submit the form from jquey code `$("form#formID").submit();`

Comment: but in this case the form is submitting to an action inside an MVC controller.  I would have no idea about the syntax for a javascript button submitting the form to a controller and passing in the value of the hidden text boxes, etc.

Comment: Dont worry about that the hidden fields will get post in forms collection and your form will also get post to right action.
for more information on forms collection have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391318/asp-net-mvc-forms-collection-when-submitting

Comment: If you care to post the JavaScript code you're using, we can probably show you how to amend it to work as a two-step process prior to the form submission...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use jQuery (which provides a nice abstraction for dealing with `XMLHttpRequest` objects), you can do something like this, using [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$(function(){
    $('#your-submit-button').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.get('your-action-url', { /* your data */ }, function(response, status, jqxhr){

            // this is the callback of the request for your geocode info
            // response is whatever your action returns; I recommend JSON

            // bind your values to their relevant inputs
            $('#your-latitude-input').val(response.latitude); // and so on

            $('#your-form-id').submit(); // when called with no parameters, triggers form submission
        });
    });
});
```

This obviously includes no error-handling and makes some assumptions...